# Trouble with switch statements for multiple commands in my C shell program - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, shell, switch-statement

Im Writing a Shell in C that parses the command and the argument, echo hello world for example, echo == the command and hello world == the argument, printing hello world. But adding multiple commands keep failing for some reason

```
// cmd.h
int cmdinterperter(char string[BUFSIZE], char * cmd1, char * cmd2)
{
    int loop = 1;
    struct info array1;
    addcmds(&array1);
    while(loop == 1)
    {
        printf("-> ");
        fgets(string, BUFSIZE, stdin);
        char input[BUFSIZE];
        strcpy(input, string);
        cmd1 = strtok(input, " \n");
        cmd2 = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        //printf("%s, %s\n", array1.cmds[0], array1.cmds[3]);
        for(int i = 0; i < NUMOFCMDS; i++)
        {
           if(cmd1 == NULL)
           {
               printf("No Command Called\n");
               cmdinterperter(string, cmd1, cmd2);
           }
           
           if(strcmp(cmd1, array1.cmds[i]) == 0)
           {
                switch(i){
                    case 2:
                      if(cmd2 == NULL)
                      {
                          printf("Arguments -> echo Hello World, Prints Hello World\n");
                          cmdinterperter(string, cmd1, cmd2);
                      }
                      printf("%s\n", cmd2);
                      break;
                    case 3:
                      if(cmd2 == NULL)
                      {
                          printf("Arguments -> cmd ls, Runs ls on the shell\n(bash for unix, cmd.exe for windows)\n");
                          cmdinterperter(string, cmd1, cmd2);
                      }
                      printf("Command Ran!\n");
                      break;
                    case 0:
                      if(cmd2 == NULL)
                      {
                          printf("Arguments -> cmd ls, Runs ls on the shell\n(bash for unix, cmd.exe for windows)\n");
                          cmdinterperter(string, cmd1, cmd2);
                      }
                      system(cmd2);
                      break;
                    default:
                      printf("%s i the wrong command, please try again\n", cmd1);
                      break;
                }
           }
           else
           {
              printf("%s is the wrong command, please try again\n", cmd1);
           }
           cmdinterperter(string, cmd1, cmd2);
           if(!cmd2)
           {
              cmdinterperter(string, cmd1, cmd2);
           }
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

This only makes the one with the case 0 work, but anything else not work like case 3 for example, whats the problem?

I didnt want to use an if statment mess as i did to other projects i made, so i tried an list of commands as an array (array being in the zivterm.h file

```
// zivterm.h
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define BUFSIZE 255
#define VER 0.0
#define NUMOFCMDS 10

struct info
{
    char *cmds[NUMOFCMDS];
};

void addcmds(struct info *array1)
{
    array1->cmds[3] = "echo";
    array1->cmds[0] = "cmd";
}

void init()
{
    printf("-------------------------------\n");
    printf("ZivTerm v%0.2f | Made By zvqle!\n", VER);
    printf("-------------------------------\n\n");
    sleep(2);
}
```

Whats The issue?

also heres main.c for the people intrested

```
// main.c
#include "cmd.h"


//What Gets Run At Runtime
int main()
{
    int l = 0;
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    char * cmd;
    char * argument;
    init();
    cmdinterperter(buffer, &cmd, &argument);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: You already have a loop in the `cmdinterperter` function. Why do you call `cmdinterperter` recursively instead of just continuing the loop?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude For some reason the loop keeps exiting when no command is called for example

Comment: @zvqlealt If you can't figure out why it's not working the way you want it to, blindly adding recursion is not to actually solve the problem.  Hope if a very poor foundation to write software.

Comment: After the declaration `struct info array1;` the code calls `addcmds(&array1);` which initializes exactly two of the array entries. The other 8 entries are never initialized. Therefore, they have indeterminate values, and must not be used.

Comment: The parameters that you are passing to `cmdinterpreter` serve no purpose, and are the wrong type. The compiler should be warning you about that. They should be removed from `main`, and declared as local variables in the `cmdinterpreter` function itself.